# reading a binary file in C resulting in seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binaryfiles

I can write to binary file and read it on the same execution. But if I execute the program later just to read from the file, it results in seg fault.
I have hard-coded everything and omitted error checking for the sake of simplicity of question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Details {
     int num;
     char *name;
}details;

int writeData(char *, details *);
int readData(chhar *);
int main() {
        details *new;
        new = (details *)malloc(sizeof(new));
        new->num = 8;
        new->name = "Name";
        writeData("filename", new);
        readData("filename");      //no error on this instance
}

int writeData(char *name, details *new) {
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(name, "wb+");
        fwrite(&new, sizeof(new), 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
 }

 int readData(char *name) {
        details *new;
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(name, "rb");
        fread(&new, sizeof(new),1,fp);
        printf("%d\n", new->num);
        printf("%s\n", new->name);
        fclose(fp);
 }
```

But if I

```
 //writeData("filename", new);
```

and compile again and run with only

```
 readData("filename");
```

then it results in seg fault.
I've tried everything in my knowledge. What I am unable to understand is that file-to-be-read exists, it should not matter whether I recompile the code or not.

Comment: `sizeof(new)` is the same as `sizeof(details*)`. I.e. it gives you the size of the *pointer* and not what it points to. Use `sizeof *new` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading and writing pointers is useless. `write` will not write a pointed-to object, `read` will not magically allocate memory for you and read the pointed-to object.

Since the type you want to store itself contains a pointer, reading and writing it directly won't work either. Only structs without any pointers in them can be read and written safely.

That is, if your struct were like this

```
typedef struct Details {
     int num;
     char name[SOME_SIZE];
} details;
```

you would be able to read and write it like this

```
 fwrite(new, sizeof(*new), 1, fp);

 new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
 fread(new, sizeof(*new), 1, fp);
```

but the `char*` member means this simple method will fail.

You need to write a *serialisation* and *deserialisation* functions for your data type, and use them to read and write objects of that type.

Comment: Will you please guide me a little bit in the direction of said routines? Are these supposed to cast pointers to appropriate types?

Comment: @MRR That would somewhat too broad. I suggest you google the terms and try to follow examples, and if that fails, ask a separate question.

Comment: @MRR But basically, in the simplest case, you read/write a struct member-wise, and when it's a pointer you read/write the pointed-to object rather than the pointer itself, possibly recursively.